# 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' version issue in Mobile Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-storage

My Mobile Service worked great till I install 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage': 4.3.0.0 through NuGet from Visual Studio.

After the installation of it, Mobile Services shows

**Error
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage': 4.3.0.0. Please change your project to use version '3.1.0.1' which is the one currently supported by the hosting environment.**

Does Mobile Service only support 3.1.0.1 not the latest one? Or any other configuration I can modify to make it work?

much appreciated for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, there's already a solution and I verified correct.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2014/10/10/azure-mobile-services-net-backend-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly.aspx

1. backup your project.
2. find a clean packages.config
3. copy content from it and replace to my existing problematic packages.config
4. open the package manager console    and type:  Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 3.1.0.1
5. Clean the Build.  Then Build
6. Publish again to Azure Mobile Services.
7. done.

Bottomline: if you want to use Mobile Services, PLEASE DO NOT USE NuGet to install latest WindowsAzure.Storage cause Azure Mobile Services currently doesn't support the latest Storage client which is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when working on an Azure Mobile Service project (.NET Backend). However, I could not downgrade to Azure.Storage 3.1.0.1 because it requires Ms.Data.OData; 5.6.0 (exact version). Even having the assemblyBinding which redirects all versions to MS.Data.OData to 5.6.2, still did not work.

At the end, I had to uninstall almost all Nuget packages, including Azure.MobileServices.Tables, .BackEnd, and .Enitity. This removed almost all Nuget packages. After that, I was able to install WindowsAzure.Storage 3.1.0.1

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 3.1.0.1
```

Then reinstalling all the packages that I removed earlier (Azure.MobileServices.Tables, .Backend, etc). This worked for me. Hope it helps somebody else too